# How to make cursor goes the buttons and highlight them in turn. With use Jquery method like .each and mouseenter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

> *Problem:* When the cursor moves to a specific button, all buttons highlight. When the cursor moves out of a specific button, then just that one gets un-highlighted.
>   *Expected:* Moving between the backlit buttons each alternately

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('li').on('mouseenter', function () {
        $('li').each(function () {
            $(this).css('background-color', '#ef1909');
        }).on('mouseleave', function () {                         
            $(this).css('background-color', '#89F9DD');                    
       });
    });
});
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    transition: 0.1s; }

body {
    background-color: #efeded;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #303030; }

.container {
    max-width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto; }

h3 {
    color: #C3FF00;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em; }

h4 {
    text-transform: uppercase; }

.menu .nav-menu-prog ul li,
.menu .nav-menu-tech ul li {
    padding: 0.5em;
    background-color: #89f9dd;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 2px;  }

.menu .nav-menu-prog ul li,
.menu .nav-menu-tech ul li {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    margin-top: 1em;  }
.main-list{
    max-width: 10em;  }

.campus-board{
    max-width:10em;}
.finger-board{
    max-width:10em;}
.peg-board{
    max-width:10em;}
.roller-pull{
    max-width:10em;}
.trx{
    max-width:10em;}

.roll-heal{
    max-width: 10em; }
.drop-knee{
    max-width: 10em;}
.jump-up{
    max-width: 10em;}
.tap-on-tip{
    max-width: 10em;}
.front-step{
    max-width: 10em;}
.back-step{
    max-width: 10em;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="menu">
        <div class="nav-menu-prog">
        <ul>
           <li class="main-list">Programs</li>
           <li class="campus-board"><a id="campus-training" href="#cbt">Campus board training</a></li>
           <li class="finger-board"><a id="finger-training" href="#fbt">Finger board training</a></li>
           <li class="peg-board"><a id="peg-training" href="#pbt">Peg board training</a></li>
           <li class="roller-pull"><a id="roller-training">Roller pull-up training</a></li>
           <li class="trx"><a id="trx-training">TRX training</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Each element `<li>` tag have to uses JQuery .each() iterator for prevent duplicate code.
My purpose is create event that will respond on mouse trigger when cursor will move to the button and in this moments button is highlight. But when cursor leave the specific button or one of most buttons the event ends and button stay same color with other buttons.

Perhaps I understand where is problem occur in my code partiarly. 
When event listener 'mouseenter' wait while cursor move into the event zone then event  handler doesn't executing task correctly.  In its turn highlighting all `<li>` element. Then the mouse moves out from `<li>` element and after that the event handler stops working. But that doesn't happen and against it still work.

Comment: remove the `each` loop

Comment: Many thanks for answer, but i mean without duplicate code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as A. Wolff said:

```
$('li').on('mouseenter', function () {
    $(this).css('background-color', '#ef1909');                      
}).on('mouseleave', function () {                         
    $(this).css('background-color', '#89F9DD');                    
});
```

Snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('li').on('mouseenter', function () {
      $(this).css('background-color', '#ef1909');       
  }).on('mouseleave', function () {                    
      $(this).css('background-color', '#89F9DD');  
  });
});
```

```css
.menu .nav-menu-prog ul {
  list-style: none;
}
.menu .nav-menu-prog ul li,
.menu .nav-menu-tech ul li {
    padding: 0.5em;
    background-color: #89f9dd;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 2px;  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="menu">
        <div class="nav-menu-prog">
        <ul>
           <li class="main-list">Programs</li>
           <li class="campus-board"><a id="campus-training" href="#cbt">Campus board training</a></li>
           <li class="finger-board"><a id="finger-training" href="#fbt">Finger board training</a></li>
           <li class="peg-board"><a id="peg-training" href="#pbt">Peg board training</a></li>
           <li class="roller-pull"><a id="roller-training">Roller pull-up training</a></li>
           <li class="trx"><a id="trx-training">TRX training</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. But i have to do it with each <li> elements. It.'s means more write code then i want. For example: this code i should repeat 13 time it's difficult. Must be easy way perhaps through loop with .each() method or may be use згку JS

Comment: No, you don't need to use each loop. This will be applied for every <li> element in document

Comment: Take a look at the snippet in answer

Comment: You mean if i use my logic for specific situation that work for all <li> elements even that i will create in future? Can you help me understand how i could use some  loop (Jquery or JavaScript) in my situation, I'm really don't want repeat code many times. Many Thanks for help...

Comment: Yes, this piece of jquery code will be applied to every <li> element that is in document. Try it out. I suggest that you add specific class to li elements that you want to be highlighted. Example: "$('li.highlighted').on('mouseenter', function ()..."

Comment: No need to repeat or loop, each loop is not practical for this situation. This is really all you need.